# H­ow d­oes List::in­sert w­ork with a­rr­a­ys­

Tags: c++

I am on youtube looking over tutorials. One had a block of code using the list library as such:

```
int arr1[5]{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
list<int> list1;
list1.insert(list1.begin(), arr1, arr1 + 5);
```

My question is, how can one use an array like this? Last I checked, arr1 is an array not a pointer that you use to loop through elements. How does the insert function work?

Comment: In most cases, arrays are automatically converted to pointers to their first elements. It happens here too.

Comment: This is commonly known as "decay". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an array is used by name, it's name references to first element of the array. For an array `arr` whenever you say `arr[x]`, `[]` is defined in terms of pointers. It means start at a pointer referencing `arr` and move `x` steps ahead. A size of each step is the `sizeof` datatype your array is made up of. Thus,`arr[x]` can also be written as `*(arr + x)`, dereferencing the pointer after x steps.

Now speaking of your list insertion, it means copy all the elements between pointers `arr` and `arr + 5` to the list.

Comment: thanks for this! Clarifies stuff my prof skipped over in class. Damn nobody told me this

Answer (score 0):

`arr1` can be used as a pointer to the beginning of the array, because it gets converted automatically.